# Honda oydessy year 2000 does not go in reverse does not go forward but you can drive it in netural

Tags: automatic-transmission, odyssey

I have a 2000 Honda Odyssey that only drives in neutral; no reverse or forward. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: The transmission is shot. The Odyssey was built using the same transmission used in Civic and Accord. They cannot stand up to the extra weight which the van has, so fail readily after they get a bit old. Take it to a transmission shop. I'm sure they'll tell you the same thing.

Comment: @paulster2 You have obviously seen this before.  Does the vehicle really drive in neutral?

Comment: @HandyHowie You have to give it a little push... and ideally it's sitting on a hill... but sure ;-)

Comment: @HandyHowie - I was wondering about that myself ... but as Lynn says, a good push will get it done, lol! (Downhill with a back wind is a good choice as well.)

Answer (score 2):

As @ᴘᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 said, this appears to be a known issue with Honda Odyssey Model Years 1999-2001. From the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honda_Odyssey_(North_America)#Transmission_issues) for this set of model years:

> The 4-speed automatic transmission in 1999 to 2001 models had serious
>   problems with transmission durability. Honda spokesman Mike Spencer
>   stated that four-speed models were afflicted with a bad bearing that
>   could break apart, scattering fragments of metal that clogged fluid
>   passageways in the transmission, causing it to shift erratically.